# auto generated functions by solidity

Tags: solidity, address.transfer, function

`send` and `transfer` are automatically generated function to send ether(wei) to some address.

I tried to search a list of such functions in solidity documentation but to no avail, can someone help here? And, are the lists of auto generated functions different by types of addresses (EOA vs contracts)?

Comment: what you mean send and transfer are automatically generated function? Do you mean global functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`send` and `transfer` are built-in function of address type.
For details ,please refer to official docs - https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/types.html?highlight=send#members-of-addresses